# Vagrant + external editor that actually connects to vagrant?

Tags: node.js, workflow, vagrant, webstorm

I’m new to Vagrant and currently I’m using WebStorm.
The suggested workflow should be to use your editor while compiling stuff in vagrant. My question is: at what point should I stop and use my own compilers?

WebStorm is cool because it connects to your stuff and do things like REPL and autocompletion based on your code etc.

How does that works if my nodejs interpreter is on the VM? Should I install my own nodejs? If so, what’s the point of having a virtual machine?

Maybe there is a way to tell Webstorm to use the VM interpreter but how?

Comment: What is your problem and/or what you can't accomplish in your current set up? Are you saying you want Webstorm to connect to your (logically if not physically) remote node instance in the VM managed by Vagrant (for debugging presumably)?

Comment: Webstorm asks me where is the node interpreter, but I don’t have any in my computer, it’s on the VM how to connect?

Comment: got it - yes, in this case you'd just install node on your local machine so your IDE can access it. I know this will raise your "what is the point of the VM" question. Generally, I think when most developers are using VMs it is to better simulate a production environment they are targeting. There are other reasons, but it's a more general topic.

Comment: so if my code is never going in production anyways there is no point in using vagrant right?

Comment: I wouldn't say "no point" necessarily, but generally you're correct. I like to keep some things in VMs to keep my machine a little cleaner. However, if you're just wanting to play around with Node (or whatever) a little bit, a VM probably isn't doing much for you except adding another layer.